Is it possible to skip pages in the Apps Script execution log?
I have several projects which have which include timed 1-minute triggers. This results in a whole lot of executions per day. Currently the settings allow for displaying 200 rows per page, but if you have 3/4 such triggers in addition to an OnEdit trigger, you're looking at over 1-2k executions per day.
When looking for the logs of something which happened a few days prior, I find myself clicking through 20-30 pages of executions manually until I can locate it. This can take 2-3 minutes each time. Is there an easier way to skip to a page directly instead of manually clicking the arrows?

Doesn't your editor have the ability to search with regex?

You can only add some filters to your executions page, Time, status, ran as, type, deployment or trigger id.
Another approach to ease your logs lecture would be to store relevant info in a side sheets.It would allow you to easily filter depending on the info you're trying to get in your logs!
